# Intel vaapi : can't play mkv with vlc

Tags: video, vlc, hardware-acceleration, mkv, vaapi

I can find why I can't play any mkv file with vlc, it seems there is a drawing error, is there a workaround or something ? I have optimus (intel+nvidia) and i'm using bumblebee with last nvidia driver 358.

```
VLC media player 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax) (revision 2.2.1-0-ga425c42)
[0000000001686148] core libvlc: Lancement de vlc avec l'interface par défaut. Utilisez « cvlc » pour démarrer VLC sans interface.
libva info: VA-API version 0.38.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_38
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
[00007f5994c75a08] avcodec decoder: Using OpenGL/VAAPI/libswscale backend for VDPAU for hardware decoding.
[00007f59986dbea8] adjust filter error: Unsupported input chroma (VDV0)
[00007f59986dd2a8] sharpen filter error: Unsupported chroma (VDV0)
[00007f59986dd2a8] vdpau_sharpen filter error: sharpening/blurring not supported by VDPAU device
[00007f598803c038] core video output error: Failed to create video filter2 'sharpen'
[00007f598803c038] core video output error: Failed to add filter 'sharpen'
[VS] error (vdpDecoderRender_h264): no surfaces left in buffer
[VS] error (vdpDecoderRender_h264): no surfaces left in buffer
[VS] error (vdpDecoderRender_h264): no surfaces left in buffer
[VS] error (vdpDecoderRender_h264): no surfaces left in buffer
[VS] error (vdpDecoderRender_h264): no surfaces left in buffer
[VS] error (vdpVideoSurfaceGetBitsYCbCr): not implemented conversion VA FOURCC Y -> VDP_YCBCR_FORMAT_YV12
[00007f59985cc008] vdpau_chroma filter error: video surface export failure: VDP_STATUS_INVALID_Y_CB_CR_FORMAT
[VS] error (vdpVideoSurfaceGetBitsYCbCr): not implemented conversion VA FOURCC Y -> VDP_YCBCR_FORMAT_YV12
[00007f59985cc008] vdpau_chroma filter error: video surface export failure: VDP_STATUS_INVALID_Y_CB_CR_FORMAT
[VS] error (vdpVideoSurfaceGetBitsYCbCr): not implemented conversion VA FOURCC Y -> VDP_YCBCR_FORMAT_YV12
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok all i had to do according this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=199749 is to launch vlc with `vlc --avcodec-hw=vaapi` or to change vlc settings in "codec" and choose vaapi via x11 instead of vdpau.

Comment: Thanks for this post! You can make this setting permanent by editing your `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc` file and setting `avcodec-hw=vaapi`.

Comment: I found that while using this switch made video visible again, it would not scale up from the original video size to the size of my monitor.

Answer (score 1):

If you like your system clean, you can also remove vdpau drivers (packages look like vdpau-driver-all:amd64 and mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64). This will force the use of VAAPI.