# Reason why syslog file is so huge in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: root, disk-usage

I recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from 18.04 LTS. It's been not even a week since the update and I get the error `Low Disk Space on Filesystem root`. I have allocated 20 GB of memory to root directory out of which 5 GB is taken just by "/var/log/syslog" file.

Is it safe to remove this file?

Also can someone please help me to find out what is the root cause of this and how to get rid of this? I find it abnormal as it wrote 5 GB of system log data in less than a week.

Here's an example of what's being repeated over and over in the syslog:

```
Nov 9 08:19:43 giri org.gnome.Nautilus[4933]: [00007fcd50476a10] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Nov 9 08:19:43 giri org.gnome.Nautilus[4933]: [00007fcd50476a10] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Nov 9 08:19:43 giri org.gnome.Nautilus[4933]: [00007fcd50476a10] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
```

Comment: I am getting the following errors which are repeated significantly large no of times:
Nov  9 08:19:43 giri org.gnome.Nautilus[4933]: [00007fcd50476a10] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Nov  9 08:19:43 giri org.gnome.Nautilus[4933]: [00007fcd50476a10] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Nov  9 08:19:43 giri org.gnome.Nautilus[4933]: [00007fcd50476a10] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.

Comment: I took bits of this error and used them as search terms and it seems this might have something to do with VLC.  Copy-paste `vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure` into your favorite search engine and see if anything seems familiar to you.

Comment: Yes. I came across [this post](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/disabling-nvidia-driver-logging-errors/20258/2). I have an internal (Intel) as well as an external (Nvidia) graphics card.  I remember using Intel graphics card for a brief period of time and again I switched back to Nvidia. As of now I am using Nvidia.

Comment: I think these questions may be related to your issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/769585/vlc-cant-take-snapshots-anymore-due-to-corrupt-vdpau-video-surface-error | https://askubuntu.com/questions/714363/intel-vaapi-cant-play-mkv-with-vlc | https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561565/i-dont-know-what-is-producing-the-gigabytes-of-error-in-syslog